# How to get 10 integer from user and put them in an Array in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I think the question is quite open. I need to take 10 integers from user but all I can is taking one with like this:

```
echo "Please enter some input: "
read input_variable
echo "You entered: $input_variable"
```

But I need to take 10. First question is there some kind of for loop to increment each with each take and finish when it hit 10?

And how do I put these inputs to an array?

Comment: have a look at http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Looping-Constructs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read multiple, space-separated values from one line:

```
read a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9 a10
echo "First value: $a1"
echo "Second value: $a2"
# etc.
```

The `read` command will read a single line, but break the line into words based on whitespace and assign them to the given names in order. If there are fewer numbers entered, the later variables remain unset. If there are more than 10 numbers, `a10` will hold the remaining values.

To use an array, use the `-a` flag to put all values in a single array instead:

```
read -a arr
echo "First value: ${arr[0]}"
echo "Second value: ${arr[1]}"
# etc.
```

Comment: i manage the first part just before you explained :) but i still don't get how to do with the array.I read the inputs and got 10 int from int1 to int10 what will i do next.What will i flag?

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in the code that accesses the array.

Answer (score 1):

Use `read -a` like this:

```
read -p "Enter an array: " -a arr
echo "You entered: ${arr[@]}"
```

Comment: i don't quite understand your answer.Can you explain a little more

Comment: Well it accepts an array from user (though it wont limit that to 10 elements)

Comment: But you can count # of entered elements using `${#arr[@]}` and prompt user again if required.

Comment: @judge, you are expected to enter 10 space-separated numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Coming late to the party:

```
nums=()
for i in {1..10}; do
    read -p "$i. Enter a number: " num
    # ... validate response is a number, if you like ...
    nums+=("$num")
done
printf "%s\n" "${nums[@]}"
```